# How to do while loop until my output has reached

Tags: python, loops

I have a password verifier and I have made it that when there is less than 6 digits to change a variable called "invalid" to 1 and if it is is more than 16 digits to change a variable called "invalid" to 1. How do I make it that when the variable is one for it to run the code again and if it is on zero for it to stop. Is there a way to start the code again when the invalid variable is one?

Comment: Post your code and an "if" with a break or exit or one of those should work, depending on your code. Which we cant see.

Comment: Its good practice to show people the code you're currently using. To me it's unclear what you're trying to achieve and what's going wrong.

Comment: invalid = 0
print ("Your password needs to have the following: ")
print ()
print ("At least 1 lowercase character")
print ()
print ("At least 1 uppercase character")
print ()
print ("1 of these special characters ($#@)")
print ()
print ("Has to have a minium of 6 characters and a maximum of 16 characters")
print ()
password = input("Please input a Password:  ")

                 
if len(password)<6:
    invalid = 1

if len(password)>16:
    invalid = 1

if (invalid == 0):
    print ("Valid")

if (invalid == 1):
    print ("invalid")

Comment: how do i put code in I'm sorry I'm new here

Comment: @AithanPerera I added an answer that lives up to your password rules.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, after reading your current code:

```
import re

print("""
    Your password needs to have the following:
    
    At least 1 lowercase character

    At least 1 uppercase character

    1 of these special characters ($#@)

    Has to have a minium of 6 characters and a maximum of 16 characters
""")

invalid = 1
while invalid:
    password = input("Please input a Password: ")
    if len(password)<6 or len(password)>16:
        print("Password length invalid, please try again")
    elif not any(x in password for x in {"$","#","@"}):
        print("Password must contain one of these special characters: $#@, please try again")
    elif not re.search(r"[A-Z]", password) or not re.search(r"[a-z]", password):
        print("Password must contain at least one capital and one lower case character, please try again")
    else:
        print("Password valid")
        invalid = 0
```

Result:

```
    Your password needs to have the following:

    At least 1 lowercase character

    At least 1 uppercase character

    1 of these special characters ($#@)

    Has to have a minium of 6 characters and a maximum of 16 characters

Please input a Password: hejhejhejhejhejhejhejhej
Password length invalid, please try again
Please input a Password: hej
Password length invalid, please try again
Please input a Password: hejhejhej
Password must contain one of these special characters: $#@, please try again
Please input a Password: hejhejhej#
Password must contain at least one capital and one lower case character, please try again
Please input a Password: Hejhejhej#
Password valid
```

Comment: When i used this code i straight away put in a correct answer I didn't work

Comment: @AithanPerera and what did you input? Works fine on my machine using Python 3.9.9.

Comment: im using Python IDLE Shell 3.10.3 and i used the input of 12aA#11

Comment: @AithanPerera If I input your password, it works fine: `Please input a Password: 12aA#11` Result: `Password valid`. What error are you getting?

Comment: It works now sorry

Comment: @AithanPerera no need to be sorry, we're all learning. :-)

Comment: :) ..............................

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a variable to check if the conditions are met.
The while loop will run until password is of right size

```
check = 1
while check == 1:
    input = input('Give your password')
    if 6 < len(input) < 16:
        check = 0
```

Comment: how would I do it if i had more conditions such as  At least 1 lowercase character

    At least 1 uppercase character

    1 of these special characters ($#@)

Comment: if ((6 < len(input) < 16) and len([i for i in input if i in ['@', '!', '*', '&']]) >= 1 and len([i for i in input if i.isupper() == True] >= 1)):
        check = 0

Comment: See comment above, just add two extra checks with "and" statements. One is for symbols, you should expand the list to contain every symbol you want and declare it as a variable to refactor the line I typed. The last check counts the number of uppercase letters. If you don't understand the method, please google "list comprehension python".

Answer (score 0):

You can add some if-statements. You can use the "break" statement to break out of the loop. Meaning that when "break" is executed the loop will no longer be executed.
I don't know what your code looks like but you could do something like this.

```
if invalid == 0:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
invalid = True
while(invalid):
    # your code here, accept/recheck password
    if not(len(password)<6 or len(password)>16):
        invalid = False # passw valid, breaks before next iteration
```

True and False would seem like better alternatives to 0 and 1 for your application, would still work either way if you choose to use 0 and 1

Comment: MY FINAL CODE: https://pastebin.com/DLmvnaYi

Comment: @AithanPerera Looks very good!